# Using 2 wifi for 2 different udp clients

Tags: c#, wifi, udpclient

I have a  c# win app.
I am using wifi for internet connectivity.

I currently have a udp client that uploads to my server data.
I have another udp client that uploads to my local lan server.

The data is being sent 10 times a second on both udp channels.

Sometimes the data is not sent and I get on one of them a 'connection refused' error.
My thinking is that if I plug in another wifi into my usb port I would get another dhcp address assigned and I could send data on 1 wifi point and data on the other.

Can this be done. Can I specify which ip address to send data FROM?

Thanks

This is my current code:

internal class WanService
{
private static UdpClient _udpCloudClient;

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                _udpCloudClient = new UdpClient(Constants.GetUdpServerIp(), Constants.ServerUploadPort);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle
            }

            if (_udpCloudClient?.Client == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (_udpCloudClient.Client.Connected) return;
        }
    }

    public static void SendImage()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_udpCloudClient == null) return;

       
            _udpCloudClient.Send(Globals.FinalPacket, Globals.FinalPacket.Length);
          
        }
        catch (SocketException sex)
        {
            //handle
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //handle
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((_udpCloudClient != null && !_udpCloudClient.Client.Connected) || (_udpCloudClient == null))
            {
                Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending your data and are you calling [`UdpClient.Connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.connect?view=netcore-3.1) anywhere? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @MindSwipe Hi, yes 2 secs. thanks

Comment: The error is due to the port number already in use.  So most likely an old connection is not closing.  To verify that a connection did close from cmd.exe > Netstat -a and check the status of the port you are using.

Comment: @jdweng no port is not in use. And that does not address my question of using 2 separate wifi dongles for 2 separate udp clients which use different ports

Comment: @MindSwipe My code is fin. I just wanted to know if I can use 2 different wifi connections at the same time

Comment: As long as the port number are different and you have a route between the clients and servers.  You cannot have IP conflicts,  and you need routes.  It doesn't matter the physical hardware connection.

Comment: @jdweng hi, sorry for delay.  I know it is not ip conflicts I imagine it is 2 sources of data sharing the same bandwidth?

Comment: The bandwidth is the limits of the hardware connection(s).  Using two Wifi Connections may (or may not) increase bandwidth. Bandwidth depends on a lot of factors.  Yes it is possible to use two Wifi connections, but if not done correctly you could have issues.

Comment: @jdweng agreed. I believe I may have a way of doing this (for my User Case)  I have order a wifi dongle and it will be here tomorrow. So will know then!  Will post results.. thanks

Comment: The route is determined by the IP address and the mask.  So if you have two Wiki connections, the subnet determined by the mask and each Wifi would be in a different subnet.

Comment: so are you suggestion there would be no benefit if I could direct the udps to different wifi points if they are still using the same subnets?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot choose the sending IP address directly using such a high level client, that's done by windows.

If you have the chance to modify server and client side, it might be a good idea to use a some kind of a library that handles lossy connections for you. I'm thinking about [GRPCs](https://grpc.io/) streaming capabilities.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot see how that will help. But thanks